# How to write double for loop code more pythonically

Tags: python

I wrote the following code.
I have written double for loop, is there a way to improve this code pythonically?
Please let me know if you have a good method or syntax.

```py
for i, (product, new_category) in enumerate(zip(interpark.products_name, interpark.new_category)):
    for j, (word, standard) in enumerate(zip(filterword.word, filterword.category)):
        if word in product:
            interpark.new_category[i] = standard
            print('product:' + product + '\t' + 'new category:' + interpark.new_category[i])
```

Comment: Its hard to make a suggestion without more context. There is a lot going on. Perhaps the answer is to break out some code into a function rather than trying to make the loops readable. Also do you really need those zips in there and the enumerates. They are the cause of most of the visual noise.

Comment: Why do you consider it un-pythonic?

Comment: The loops don't use either `new_category` or `j` - why are they included in the `for` statements?

Comment: `zip` and `enumerate` both return objects that can be assigned to *variables* which might make the `for` statements easier on the eye if you can come up with variable names that make sense.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'll revise the code.

Comment: The need for the zips arise from the parallel lists in your data structures . Perhaps making a list of dicts with both fields in might be worth considering. It’s hard to understand the best solution with so little context.